# How to stop AlgoliaSearchHelper .search() from revoking my numericRefinements

Tags: algolia, instantsearch.js, react-instantsearch, instantsearch

I'd really appreicate any input on how to fix the issue presented below! I already found the cause of the issue but I am not too sure how to fix it.

### Use Case

I created my own custom range connector that takes in 2 attributes (a minAttribute and a maxAttribute) instead of 1. The way it works is as follows:

- when a user enters a user_min value, the custom range connector will refine to show objects with a maxAttribute > user_min
- when a user enters a user_max, the custom range connector will refine to show objects with a minAttribute < user_max.
- If the user enters both a user_min and user_max then it just finds the intersection of the previous scenarios.

### Issue

Currently when a user inputs a number outside the bounds, the search is not refining to show "0 results" and instead just shows all the data in my index.

#### Example

I have 3 objects in my index -> {minPrice: 10, maxPrice: 20}, {minPrice: 30, maxPrice: 40}, {minPrice: 50, maxPrice: 60}

Now if the user inputs a max value of 5, instead of showing "0 results", it shows all the data in my index ("3 results" in this case)

### Cause of Issue

Note: I am using this file but with my own custom logic (https://github.com/algolia/instantsearch/blob/master/packages/instantsearch.js/src/connectors/range/connectRange.ts)

After looking at the connectRange function, I see that the issue stems in the `_refine` function

When I do

```
const refinedState = getRefinedState(
          helper,
          currentRange,
          nextMin,
          nextMax
        );
```

The logs of the refinedState correctly shows the applied numericRefinement

```
refinedState: {
    disjunctiveFacets: [...]
    facets: []
    ...
    ...
    numericRefinements : {
        maximumPrice : {}
        minimumPrice : {<= : [5] }
    }
}
```

but then in the next step in the `_refine` function, it sets a new state for the helper instance and then does a .search()

```
        if (refinedState) {
          helper.setState(refinedState).search();
        }
      };
```

After applying the search for the new state, when I console log the helper instance and I look at the state object, the numericRefinement in the refinedState was removed.

```
helper: {
    client: {}
    lastResults: {}
    ...
    ...
    state: {
        disjunctiveFacets: [...]
        facets: []
        ...
        ...
        numericRefinements : {
            maximumPrice : {}
            minimumPrice : {}
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see the helper instance removed the minimumPrice refinement from its state on its own. Why does the .search() function remove my refinement?